# Move a paragraph after a div with .after (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, html, paragraph

I am currently playing around with Codeacademy and I received a task, telling me to move a new paragraph, after a div. Heres what I did:

```
$('#one').after('<p>this is jquery</p>');
```

Now I want to move the new paragraph after another div, called #two, however, I am supposed to use .after, so it tells me. How would I go about moving the new paragraph, after the #two id.

Edit: Sorry, I am a beginner at this. Somehow, the stuff doesn't work in jsfiddle for me, I am most likely doing something wrong. However I will leave a couple of screenshots below:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/CbAmp.jpg

Comment: can't understand your question clearly? can you explain?

Comment: The wording needs some clearing up: you can either *insert* a *new* paragraph, or *move* an *existing* one. Do you want to move the paragraph inserted after `#one` and place it after `#two`?

Comment: Please add some HTML code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

html

```
<div id="one">one</div>
<div id="two">two</div>
```

javascript

```
$('#one').after('<p>this is jquery</p>');
$('#two').after($("#one + p"));
```

[example](http://jsfiddle.net/axrwkr/QA5hD)

Answer (score 1):

As you haven't set up the `p` as a separate variable I would do it like this:

```
$('#two').after($('#one').next('p'));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/PJff8/

My preferred way would be to set up the `p` as a variable and then you can move as much as you want without having to reselect it:

```
var p = $('<p>this is jquery</p>');
$('#one').after(p);
$('#two').after(p);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/PJff8/1/

Comment: Well formulated answer, unfortunately, that did not help me. But thank you

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly; you can use the [`next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/) in conjunction with [`insertAfter()`](http://api.jquery.com/insertAfter/), like so:

```
$('#one').after('<p>this is jquery</p>').next('p').insertAfter('#two');
```

### [jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8M4Ny/)

Comment: The assignment describes that I should only use .after to advance. However, I appreciate your answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#one').after("<p>Let's see what we can add</p>");
$('p').after($('#two'));
});
```

This will work as it has complete flow of elements.